# How to select javascript array key using variable?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have this json:

```
var myjson = [
    {"ID":1, "FullName":"Breese Dantour"},
    {"ID":2, "FullName":"Danny Xirjav"},
    {"ID":3, "FullName":"Ben Falco"}
]
```

And I tried to catch it by it's key using an array:

```
var mykey = new array();
mykey.push("ID");
mykey.push("FullName");

var res = "";
for (var i = 0; i < myjson.length; i++) {
   var inner;
   for (var c=0; c < mykey.length; c++){
      inner = inner + "<td>" + myjson[i].mykey[c] + "</td>";
   }
   res = res + "<tr>" + inner + "</tr>\n";
}
alert(res);
```

And i got this error :

```
Error: TypeError: myjson[i].mykey is undefined
```

I know this happen because `mykey` is not the key of `myjson`. But I want that `mykey` returning it's value so it read as `myjson` key.
Any other ways?

Comment: Use `myjson[i][mykey[c]]`

Comment: Also    var mykey = new array(); should be     var mykey = new Array();

Comment: @OkiErieRinaldi I've updated my answer with explanation ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `myjson[i].mykey[c]` by `myjson[i][mykey[c]]`

The reason this works is that the dot operator(`.`) has higher precedence than `[]` so the former expression is evaluated as `(myjson[i].mykey)[c]` which gives you `undefined` because `myjson[i]` doesn't have the property `mykey`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
var mykey = new array();
mykey.push("ID");
mykey.push("FullName");

var res = "";
for(var i = 0; i < myjson.length; i++){
   var inner = "";
   for (var c=0; c < mykey.length; c++){
      inner = inner+"<td>"+myjson[i][mykey[c]]+"</td>";
   }
   res = res+"<tr>"+inner+"</tr>\n";
}
alert(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get array elements by key like this:

```
myjson[i][ mykey[c] ];
```